# How to derivate $e^{g(x)}$ where $g(x) =\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}dt$?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find $f'(1)$ if $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ where $g(x) =\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}dt.$

Our lecturer told that we have to use a formula called Leibniz Formula. I found something but I'm really not sure about the result. Can anyone help?

Sorry if my formatting is wrong. I really have no idea about the LaTeX format and it is really urgent.

Comment: First show what you found and how you found it. And write down that Leibniz formula.

Comment: Why is it really urgent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f'(x) = g'(x)e^{g(x)}$ by the chain rule, with
$$
g'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t = 3x^2\cdot\left.\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right|_{t=x^3} - 2x\cdot\left.\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right|_{t=x^2} = \frac{3x^8}{1+x^5} - \frac{2x^5}{1+x^4},
$$
according to [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) (cf. 2nd line), hence
$$
f'(1) = g'(1)e^{g(1)} = \left(\frac{3}{1+1} - \frac{2}{1+1}\right) \exp\left(\int_1^1\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\right) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Yep, my result was 1/2 too. Thanks a lot for your time @Abezhiko !!!

Comment: @unitylearns You're welcome !